# nginx start (question about how to cope with linux reference manuals)

Tags: command-line, nginx

Ubuntu 14.04

Could you help me understand what does this difference mean. I'm trying to cast a look at nginx (a web-server). I would like to start it. It starts automatically, but I have stopped it. And now I would like to see what there is in the documentation:

```
michael@michael:~$ /etc/init.d/nginx -h
Usage: nginx {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|configtest|rotate|upgrade}
michael@michael:~$ cd /etc/init.d/
michael@michael:/etc/init.d$ nginx -h
nginx version: nginx/1.8.1
Usage: nginx [-?hvVtq] [-s signal] [-c filename] [-p prefix] [-g directives]

Options:
  -?,-h         : this help
  -v            : show version and exit
  -V            : show version and configure options then exit
  -t            : test configuration and exit
  -q            : suppress non-error messages during configuration testing
  -s signal     : send signal to a master process: stop, quit, reopen, reload
  -p prefix     : set prefix path (default: /usr/share/nginx/)
  -c filename   : set configuration file (default: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
  -g directives : set global directives out of configuration file
```

Well, nginx start works. But I'm a bit confused.

Could you help me understand why help invoked from different folders resulted in different message? And why man nginx doesn't say anything about starting nginx (maybe I overlooked it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the first example is executing the startup script located at /etc/init.d/nginx

In the second example you just typed in a bare name thus it looks for the command following your $PATH variable to find the first reference which will be the actual nginx binary at /usr/sbin/nginx

These are two different things, if you want to execute a file in the current directory and not automatically have bash search the locations in the $PATH variable you should prefix it with ./ like this

./nginx